# ERC20 - marketcaps

Tags: erc-20

I have been getting confused. If we look at this chart - 
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/coss/

It says split and the cap went to 11M from 3M. They announced a split. I am unsure what this means.

I think these are all ERC20 based and hence I am asking here. I have seen the same issue several times before, and hence market caps just race up.

Can someone explain how splits work and what the price does after a split?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are conflating COSS' [revenue fee split allocation](https://coss.io/coss-token-based-fee-split-allocation-tutorial) (a dividend of sorts) and an stock split - with what looks to have been a mistake on Coin Market Cap.

Looking at the [Bitcoin Talk thread for COSS](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2050735.980), you can see the answer to the same question:

> Q: Somehow MarketCap jumped from 2.9M to 12.6M today... how comes?
>
> A: That has been stated many times, CMC was not up to date and they have wrote serveral times to CMC to fix it but it took forever. Finally today the circulation supply changed and it is now correctly.

There has been no change in the price on Coin Market Cap - only the increase in market cap - and since market cap = supply * price; it seems reasonable that it just relates to an update to Coin Market Cap's data.

Comment: I was in slack and they said CMC is wrong. Is there somewhere better to check. So the marketcap is just wrong at CMC?